# Is it possible to use ROS on RPI with controller like MultiWii or similar?

Tags: arduino, ros, quadcopter

I have a quadcopter using a MultiWii(Arduino Mega) controller. I am curious if there is any way to connect it with ROS capable RPI. (That I could add to the quad itself).

Comment: What does rpi stand for?

Comment: Stands for Raspberry Pi

Comment: What does ROS stands for?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should explain acronyms when writing questions. RPI stands for Raspberry Pi as @MarkOmo already explained and ROS stands for Robot Operating System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! There is something called the [Navio+](http://www.emlid.com/shop/navio-plus/) it runs a Linux kernel on the raspberry pi with the real-time extension, and runs Adrucopter on top of that.

You can also just connect the serial pins directly to the MultiWii and let the rpi do high level control and let the MultiWii do low level control.

Edit: [Here](http://www.multiwii.com/wiki/index.php?title=Multiwii_Serial_Protocol) is the reference for the MultiWii serial protocol (MSP) it is very powerful allowing you to do everything from sending RC stick commands, to receiving and injecting GPS values.

Comment: Navio+ looks like a great solution, but since I already have a multiwii board with gps modue and rpi board I don't like the idea of spending another 200$. Do you maybe have some information about serial communication between Pi and Wii?